# How can I instantiate a C++ template with a class with specific methods

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Let's say we have a class

```
class X {
public:
  void my_method() { std::cout << "I'm X"; }
}
```

and we have a template class:

```
template<typename T> 
class Y
{
public:
    void put(typename T item) { item.my_method(); }

};
```

I want to execute `item.my_method();` if the class Y is instantiated with a X class (if not there would be a compile error). How can I work this out?

Comment: Given the answers so far, there seems to be some confusion as to what you're really asking for. Can you please clarify the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand the question because what you have works.

```
class X
{
public:
    void my_method() { std::cout << "I'm X"; }
};

class Z
{
};

template <typename T>
class Y
{
public:
    void put(T item) { item.my_method(); }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // This compiles fine
    X theX;
    Y<X> theXY;
    theXY.put( theX );

    // ERROR: This fails to compile
    Z theZ;
    Y<Z> theYZ;
    theYZ.put( theZ );
}
```

When Y is used with a class that does not have the `my_method()` member, it fails to compile.

Comment: I think OP wants that even if `Z::my_method()` exists, still compiler should report error. The `put` method should be valid only for type `X`.

Comment: @iammilind - I will try and get clarification from questioner.

Comment: You were right. It was my stupidity. The code didn't work because I splitted into .cpp and .hpp files. After putting the whole code in the header it works right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is [template specialization](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html):

```
template<>
class Y <X>
{
public:
    void put(X item) { item.my_method(); }
};
```

Comment: If the `class Y` is big then OP has to re-write everything which is not altered in actual `class Y`.

Comment: @iammilind: I would solve it by using (templated) inheritance on top of class Y. Note that the OP's question is very general, and as such, there is no way to provide a "perfect answer" to it without knowing more details.

Comment: look at my answer, I think that would make the solution smaller.

Comment: @iammilind: You're guessing what the OP _might_ have meant. I'd rather let the OP add details if the answers provided are unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you won't get a compiler error if you instantiate `Y` with a class other than `X` as long as you don't call `put` (something unique to templates).

You could use template specialization if `put` needs to do different things for different types.

Answer (score 1):

Simply un-templatize the `put` method and create it for type `X` alone. And put a check inside the method if `T` is `X`.

```
template<typename T> struct IsX;  // unimplemented for rest of types
template<> struct IsX<X> { typedef X yes; };  // implemented for 'X' alone

template<typename T> 
class Y
{
public:
  void put (X item) { typedef typename IsX<T>::yes check; item.my_method(); }
                    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ compile time ensure that it's for 'X only
};
```

Comment: Doesn't this make the whole template mechanism redundant? If you force the compiler to give an error whenever Y is anything that isn't Y<X>, why use a template with Y at all?

Comment: @trutheality, `Y<T>` can be used for other methods than `put()`. Only for `put()` we do specialization.